# Using streams to extract specific entries of a List of Maps in to a new Map

Tags: java, java-stream, bson

Given a `org.bson.Document`

```
{  
  "doneDate":"",
  "todoEstimates":"",
  "forecastDate":"",
  "cardType":{
    "projectData":[
      {
        "color":"#ffcd03",
        "boardId":"30022"
      },
      {
        "color":"#ffcd03",
        "boardId":"1559427"
      }
    ],
    "cardFields":[
      {
        "fieldName":"id",
        "fieldLabel":"Unique ID",
        "fieldType":"Integer",
        "itemType":"Long",
        "isRequired":"NO",
        "isReadOnly":"Yes",
        "isDisabled":"NO",
        "inputMethod":"System Generated",
        "defaultValue":null,
        "isUserType":"No"
      },
      {
        "fieldName":"name",
        "fieldLabel":"Title",
        "fieldType":"Single-Line Text",
        "itemType":"String",
        "isRequired":"Yes",
        "isReadOnly":"NO",
        "isDisabled":"NO",
        "inputMethod":"Manual Entry",
        "defaultValue":null,
        "isUserType":"No"
       }
    ]
}
```

How do I extract the values of `fieldName` and `fieldLabel` via streams into the following?

```
{
   "id": "Unique ID",
   "name:" "Title",
   ...
}
```

I tried the following but I get stuck at the part where I get value of the `cardFields` list.

```
document.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().equals("cardType"))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))
.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().equals("cardFields"))
        .map(e -> (Map)e.getValue()).toList();
```

Comment: Isn't it just easier to stream/filter the `$.cardType.cardFields` field directly rather than streaming/collecting+streaming/collecting?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to map this structure to a Java object and work on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution with streams:

```
Map<String, Object> fields = ((List<Map<String, Object>>) ((Map<String, Object>) document.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("cardType"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("card type not found"))
            .getValue())
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("cardFields"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("card fields not found"))
            .getValue())
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(el -> el.get("fieldName").toString(), element -> element.get("fieldLabel")));
Document result = new Document(fields);
System.out.println(result.toJson());
```

That's probably the worst code i have written - absolutely unreadable and you can't debug it. I would suggest that you do not use stream for this particular task, it isn't the right tool for it. So here is another working solution using Map.get(key):

```
Map<String, Object> cardType = (Map<String, Object>) document.get("cardType");
List<Map<String, Object>> cardFields = (List<Map<String, Object>>) cardType.get("cardFields");
Document result = new Document();
cardFields.forEach(cardField -> result.put((String) cardField.get("fieldName"), cardField.get("fieldLabel")));
System.out.println(result.toJson());
```

This is shorter, readable, you can debug it if needed and probably it's more performant. I'd say it's much better overall.

Comment: Yeah, stream certainly looks ugly here. I'll stick to the second method!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to parse your document like this:

```java
Document cardType = document.get("cardType", Document.class);
final Class<? extends List> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>().getClass();
List<Map<String, String>> fields = cardType.get("cardFields", listOfMaps);
fields.stream().map(f -> {
    System.out.println(f.get("fieldName") + ": " + f.get("fieldLabel"));
    // here you can construct your new object
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>().getClass()` is the same as `ArrayList.class`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind casting a lot, you could try following:

```
    List cardFields = (List) ((Map) document.get("cardType")).get("cardFields");

    Map<String, String> map = (Map) cardFields.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(cf -> ((Document) cf).getString("fieldName"),
                    cv -> ((Document) cv).getString("fieldLabel")));
    
    System.out.println(map);
```

or you can emit omit the casting with the following:

```
    List<Document> carFields = document.get("cardType", Document.class)
                                       .getList("cardFields", Document.class);
    Map<String, String> map = carFields.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getString("fieldName"), 
                                      v -> v.getString("fieldLabel")));
    System.out.println(map);
```

Here is the complete example running with java 17:

```
import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class Bson {

 private String json=
           """
                {
                  "doneDate": "",
                  "todoEstimates": "",
                  "forecastDate": "",
                  "cardType": {
                    "projectData": [
                      {
                        "color": "#ffcd03",
                        "boardId": "30022"
                      },
                      {
                        "color": "#ffcd03",
                        "boardId": "1559427"
                      }
                    ],
                    "cardFields": [
                      {
                        "fieldName": "id",
                        "fieldLabel": "Unique ID",
                        "fieldType": "Integer",
                        "itemType": "Long",
                        "isRequired": "NO",
                        "isReadOnly": "Yes",
                        "isDisabled": "NO",
                        "inputMethod": "System Generated",
                        "defaultValue": null,
                        "isUserType": "No"
                      },
                      {
                        "fieldName": "name",
                        "fieldLabel": "Title",
                        "fieldType": "Single-Line Text",
                        "itemType": "String",
                        "isRequired": "Yes",
                        "isReadOnly": "NO",
                        "isDisabled": "NO",
                        "inputMethod": "Manual Entry",
                        "defaultValue": null,
                        "isUserType": "No"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }     
        """;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bson bson = new Bson();
    Document document = Document.parse(bson.json);

    List cardType = (List) ((Map) document.get("cardType")).get("cardFields");

    Map<String, String> map = (Map) cardType.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(cf -> ((Document) cf).getString("fieldName"),
                    cv -> ((Document) cv).getString("fieldLabel")));
    System.out.println(map);


    List<Document> carFields = document.get("cardType", Document.class).getList("cardFields", Document.class);
    Map<String, String> map1 = carFields.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getString("fieldName"), v -> v.getString("fieldLabel")));
    System.out.println(map1);
  }
}
```

Comment: `List<Document> carFields = document.get("cardType", Document.class)
                                       .getList("cardFields", Document.class);` gave a casting error when I had tried it, had to use `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: with bson 4.4.1 and java 17 this code works

Comment: Okay, I'm on 17 but bson 4.2.3

Comment: its working for me with bson 4.2.3 as well :-) but I had to add a `}` at the end to your json in order to be able to parse it with `Document.parse`